# Using Thurstone's Law of Comparative Judgement

Tags: multiple-comparisons, ranking

I'm processing data for a listening test in which Five speaker setups played similar dialogue sections for a set of participants. Participants were given A/B comparisons for every combination of speakers where order mattered (20 comparisons) and the "winning" setup in each comparison was given a clarity rating 0-10. The end goal is to rank the five setups from best to worst. I'm looking at a paper about [Thurstone's Law of Comparative Judgement](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a543806.pdf.), and Equations 3/4 discuss a way to estimate quality difference using the comparative choice and the clarity rating given.

I have looked everywhere and I cannot figure out how to implement the following:
[image]

I have STD of AB worked out, and I understand what's within the parentheses, but how can I take the inverse CDF of the ratio of people who picked A VS. B? Everything I've read online says I need ranges of the data to do CDF, but I could be misunderstanding. Any help is greatly appreciated!